# How to append numpy array as a pickle in database record

Tags: python, postgresql, pickle

I need to append new numpy array as pickle in database record.

this code just replace new array to old one.

```
db.cursor.execute("UPDATE captures SET array_data=%s WHERE id=%s",(pickle.dumps(arr1),self.target_id))
db.conn.commit()
```

This arrays represent a image that received column by column from server.

Answer (score 0):

You are not being very clear, but my guess is, that you want something like this?

```
db.cursor.execute("UPDATE captures SET array_data=CONCAT(array_data, '<separator if you wish>', '%s) WHERE id=%s",(pickle.dumps(arr1), self.target_id))
```

CONCAT func may vary, depending on your db.

Comment: this error happend: psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "array_data" is of type bytea but expression is of type text